# is Map<string,Object> suitable for converting arbitrary object to Json format?

Tags: java, json

currently using a lot of HashMaps when need to convert some object model to json. my concern is that HashMap's overhead is too much for this task.

Pros: HashMap is very flexible in terms of using

Cons: too much overhead

there still might be one argument that these Maps will die Young.

not sure if there are better data structure or ways doing this ?

==

Map : Object means the value can be any type (List, Map, Integer, Long etc...). this is why I think it is flexible

I know those libs that can convert object to json, question is more an intermediate data structure to allow the conversion between json and real objects.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive of what the `Object` is? Perhaps share the source code.

Comment: Also, have you considered declaring classes for your object models? You could then use `Gson` to convert them into Json

Comment: Have you tried something like https://github.com/google/gson Or http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode`. It's super simple to traverse the json tree, for example:

```
String jsonInput = "{\"intKey\":1234, \"array\":[22,44,55],\"someObject\":{\"bool\":true,\"double\":2.5,\"string\":\"asdf\"}}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonInput);
node.path("intKey").asInt(); // 1234
for(JsonNode n : node.path("array")) {
    System.out.println(n.asInt()); // 22, 44, 55
}
JsonNode someObject = node.path("someObject");
someObject.path("bool").asBoolean(); // true
someObject.path("double").asDouble(); // 2.5
someObject.path("string").asText(); // asdf
```